# Google App Maker - Emailing a completed form

Tags: google-app-maker

With Google App Maker, I can make a form.  I can create a Submit button that emails to a particular email address.  And I can pass individual field values into the email.

But I want to be able to send the whole completed form exactly how it looks when the user fills out the form in the email. (If need be, sending it as an image is okay.  But sending it as an editable form is even better.)

Comment: Did you consider sending by email link to that form? Lots of templates use this approach: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/

Answer (score 0):

Server script function that will allow you to embed images into a message

```
function sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options) {

    var ImageBlob = DriveApp
        .getFileById('id')
        .getBlob()
        .setName("ImageBlob");

    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {
        htmlBody: options.html,
        inlineImages: { image: ImageBlob }
    });

    // Parameters :
    // sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
    // Name Type Description
    // recipient String Comma separated list of email addresses
    // subject String Subject of the email
    // body String Body of the email
}
```